# AngularJS Switch button How to get the state of the button

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to get the state of a button regarding if this one is set on 'on' or 'off',

I have set a function trigger by a ng-change and set a ng-init = false on it.

Once my function is trigger I would like to implement two conditions, like if it's 'on' do this... and if it's on 'off' do this else... But the fact is, I trigger only the init (false).

As you see, I tried to over init 'checked' in , but this is not working and it remains as false.

How could I handle this ?

Please, check below my script:

```js
c.getIfWorking = function(sys_id, working) {
    if (working) {
        console.log('true')
    } else {
        console.log('false')
    }
}
```

```html
<td>
    <label class="switch">
         <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn"
                ng-model='c.data.isWorking[$index]'
                ng-init="checked=false"
                ng-change='c.getIfWorking(item.sys_id, checked)'>
           <div class="slider round"><!--ADDED HTML -->
                <span class="on" ng-init="checked=true">Yes</span>
                <span class="off" ng-init="checked=false">No</span><!--END-->
            </div>
    </label>
</td>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use same variable for `ng-model` and pass the state to `ng-change` function,

should be something like below

```
<input type="checkbox" id="togBtn"
       ng-model='c.data.isWorking[$index]'
       ng-init="c.data.isWorking[$index]=false"
       ng-change='c.getIfWorking(item.sys_id, c.data.isWorking[$index])'>
```

Note: use this `ng-init="c.data.isWorking[$index]=false"` if u really want to init as its a object its default should be set while initializing the object.

Comment: I'm using right after a ng-if = 'c.data.isWorking[$index]', but working. Do you have any idea why ?
 <div ng-if='c.data.isWorking[$index]'>
     my HTML
</div>

Comment: can u elaborate it, i didn't understand what u r asking.

if its working then what u want it should not work :)

"my HTML" will/should show when checkbox is true

Comment: Sorry. I implement a <div> right after the input the solution you gave me. So the input run the function but also display extra html below if it's false but hide if it's true. In my previous exemple was the exemple of the <div>.

Comment: correct it should because of ng-if='c.data.isWorking[$index]',
when ng-if true it draws on DOM on false it removes